# How can I get the Playhead of a video in Safari?

Tags: safari, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I'm working on a video engine that is playing HLS V7 in native safari video engine.

I need to figure out which fragment is currently playing.

After reviewing the safari docs, I am having trouble figuring out what the engine is currently playing.

Is there a way to programmatically get this information from the safari video engine?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to know the URL of the currently playing fragment?

Comment: if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, `hls.js`

you can benefit from the events like:

`hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_PARSED, onLevelLoaded);`

check out all events here : https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#runtime-events

checkout demo here with real-time matrix : 
https://hls-js.netlify.com/demo/

https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#runtime-events